# BNI and BRI cash machines, what are the differences?

Tags: money, indonesia, atms

I constantly see BNI and BRI cash machines across Indonesia.

What are the differences between the two?

Comment: The same differences as between PostFinance and Credit Suisse ATMs. Every machine with a VISA sign allows you to get money from your credit card at a cost fixed by VISA and at the daily conversion rate of your credit card issuer.

Comment: Beside the fact they're just two different Indonesian banks ?

Comment: I was wondering if these actually were different banks, thought they could be part of the same group company

Comment: Just different banks. BNI sometimes seem to have higher limits though (sometimes it's possible to get 2 million while the machine states a maximum of 1,5 million).

Answer (score 8):

[Bank Rakyat Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Rakyat_Indonesia) ([BRI](http://www.bri.co.id/)) and [Bank Negara Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Negara_Indonesia) ([BNI](http://bni.co.id/id-id/Beranda.aspx)) are separate banks.  BRI is bigger and has [a more widespread ATM network](http://flights.indonesiamatters.com/1899-idr-visitors-guide/#102), with [over 20,000](http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=148820&p=irol-homeProfile) compared to [BNI's 6,000](http://www.bni.co.id/locator/atmlocator.aspx).

There's conflicting information about fees, with at least one claim that BRI has [lower fees](http://forum.virtualtourist.com/Bali-1223706-12-10058339/ATM-fees.html) but a similar forum post stating there are [no fees for most Indonesian ATMs](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/atm-withdrawal-fees-in-indonesia).

Comment: Interesting. One thing I noticed is that BNI cash points accept bank cards belonging to a wider number of networks. Anything to say about it?

Answer (score 7):

Although BRI seems to have a bigger network than BNI, there seems to be an advantage in using BNI cash machines: they usually (if not always) accept cards belonging to a larger number of card networks.

BNI cash points accept: Visa, Visa electron, MasterCard, Cirrus, Maestro, Plus, ATM Bersama, Prima, BNI, Link.

BRI cash points usually do **not** accept cards belonging to Visa. I'll try find out more on this.

[image: BNI cash point in Indonesia]

---

#### Read more

- [lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/opening-a-bank-account-in-indonesia](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/opening-a-bank-account-in-indonesia)